# Непонятное поведение deffereds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

что есть

```
       all_array = [
                {'div': 'container',
                    'ids': [
                        {'name_con': '36 конвеер', 'id': '37'},
                        {'name_con': '37 конвеер', 'id': '39'},
                        {'name_con': '40 конвеер', 'id': '40'},
                    ],
                },
                {'div': 'container100',
                    'ids': [
                        {'name_con': '100 конвеер', 'id': '38'},
                    ],
                },
                {'div': 'container104',
                    'ids': [
                        {'name_con': '11 конвеер', 'id': '194'},
                    ],
                },
            ];
    var arr = jQuery.makeArray(all_array);

$.each(arr, function (i, name) { //проходим массив всех контейнеров

        var deferreds = [];     

        for (var x = 0, cnt = name['ids'].length; x < cnt; x++) //по каждому контейнеру проходим по графикам
        {
            var name_ = name['ids'][x]['name_con'];

           (function (deferreds) {
            deferreds.push(
            $.getJSON(path + "ajax_tag?val=" + encodeURIComponent(val) + encodeURI(' and "F_TagName_ID" = ' + name['ids'][x]['id']), function (data) {
                seriesOptions[i] = {
                    name: name_,
                    data: data
                };
            })
            , seriesOptions);
            })(deferreds);
        }
        $.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function () {               
             console.log(deferreds); //тут получаю какой то бардак.
        });
    });
```

разве deffereds не должен получить лишь свои записи?

upd

чет getjson не захотел работать

вот так

```
            (function (deferreds, name_, seriesOptions, id) {
                deferreds.push($.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data_) {
                        if (data_['id'] == id)
                        {
                            seriesOptions[i] = 
                                {
                                    name: name_,
                                    data: data_['matrix']
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }), seriesOptions                            
            );
            })(deferreds, name_, seriesOptions, id);
        }
         $.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function () {
             var results = [].slice.call(seriesOptions);
             console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
        });
```

в принципе все норм окромя

```
 [null,null,{"name":"5 конвеер","data":[[1449648025000,587],
```

т.е. он пустые значения заносит. их бы вырезать или не допустить и был бы класс.

UPD

опять не пойму что происходит

```
            (function (deferreds, name_, seriesOptions, id) {
                deferreds.push($.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data_) {
                        if (data_['id'] == id)
                        {
                            console.log(name_);
                            seriesOptions[i] =
                                    {
                                        name: name_,
                                        data: data_['matrix']
                                    }
                        }
                    }
                }), seriesOptions
                        );
            })(deferreds, name_, seriesOptions, id);
        }
        $.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function () {
            console.log('===============================================================================================');
            var results = [].slice.call(deferreds);
            console.log(results);
            for (var i = 0, cnt = results.length; i < cnt; i++)
            {
                //console.log(results[i], i);
            }
        });
```

получаю

```
    37 конвеер
    /mining.../otvod/ (строка 136)
    39 конвеер
    /mining.../otvod/ (строка 136)
    194 конвеер
    /mining.../otvod/ (строка 136)
    ===============================================================================================
    /mining.../otvod/ (строка 149)
    [Object { readyState=4,  responseText="{"id":"194","matrix":[[1...5000,2277.1287111432]]}",  responseJSON={...},  ещё...}, [undefined, Object { name="194 конвеер",  data=[899]}]]
    /mining.../otvod/ (строка 151)
    40 конвеер
    /mining.../otvod/ (строка 136)
    ===============================================================================================
    /mining.../otvod/ (строка 149)
    [Object { readyState=4,  responseText="{"id":"37","matrix":[[14...[1449674981000,263.9]]}",  responseJSON={...},  ещё...}, [Object { name="40 конвеер",  data=[897]}], Object { readyState=4,  responseText="{"id":"39","matrix":[[14...],[1449674985000,131]]}",  responseJSON={...},  ещё...}, [Object { name="40 конвеер",  data=[897]}], Object { readyState=4,  responseText="{"id":"40","matrix":[[14...1449674977000,1615.9]]}",  responseJSON={...},  ещё...}, [Object { name="40 конвеер",  data=[897]}]]
    /mining.../otvod/ (строка 151)
    5 конвеер
    /mining.../otvod/ (строка 136)
    ===============================================================================================
    /mining.../otvod/ (строка 149)
    [Object { readyState=4,  responseText="{"id":"5","matrix":[[144...],[1449675085000,587]]}",  responseJSON={...},  ещё...}, [undefined, undefined, Object { name="5 конвеер",  data=[903]}]]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w2Iu.jpg

т.е. пришли ли данные того аякс запроса или не того не так уж и важно и имя он пишет другое

Comment: суть в том что не правильно используете: _deferreds_ внутри _done_ не нужен, нужно добавить параметр/параметры в `function ()` и проверять уже их значения. Можете вообще проверить что за параметры приходят в функцию _done_ вызвав внутри нее `console.log(arguments)`

Comment: не понял. можно подробнее?

Comment: _deferreds_ - это массив, в который напиханы promise, он не меняется, он как был массивом с promise, таки остался им.

Comment: _[].slice.call(deferreds)_  мне кажется вы плохо посмотрели что именно в ответе написано. Конкретно в этом месте используется объект: _arguments_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*deferreds* - это массив в который напиханы promise, он не меняется, он как был массивом с promise, таки остался им. Поэтому внутри функции он тот же, что и снаружи.

Чтобы получить результаты, нужно обратиться к справке по [*when* функции](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), в ней сказано, что если передано несколько аргументов в функцию, то и в функции *done* будет то же количество аргументов.

то есть в вашем случае должно было быть вот так

```
$.when(a1,a2,a3).done(function(a1result,a2result,a3result){ ... });
```

Но так как используется массив, то получать соответствующие результаты нужно из array-like объекта [*arguments*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

```
$.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function(){
    var results = [].slice.call(arguments);
});
```

теперь в массиве *results* находятся результаты соответствующих *promise* из массива *deferreds*

**UPDATE**

Присмотревшись, заметил еще ошибку в использовании *push*

```
deferreds.push(
    $.getJSON(path + "ajax_tag?val=" + encodeURIComponent(val) + encodeURI(' and "F_TagName_ID" = ' + name['ids'][x]['id']), function (data) {
        seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: name_,
            data: data
        };
    })
        , seriesOptions);
```

здесь вы используете переменную *seriesOptions* - она не нужна вообще.

Кроме того - нужно вернуть объект из функции, в итоге должно выглядеть так

```
deferreds.push(
    $.getJSON(path + "ajax_tag?val=" + encodeURIComponent(val) + encodeURI(' and "F_TagName_ID" = ' + name['ids'][x]['id']), function (data) {
        return {
            name: name_,
            data: data
        };
    })
);
```

Comment: а как из такой портянки сейчас данные получить? http://i.imgur.com/KvYt2Ah.jpg

Comment: @des1roer :-D ну вы б хоть написали откуда это взяли, в любом случае: на картинке массивы массивом - я так понимаю вам возвращаются массивы с точками - вот у вас в итоге оказывается один массив, в котором элементы - конкретные массивы с точками

Comment: ну и судя по самом объекту, это результат _getJson_

Comment: может я неправильно полученные данные обрабатываю? в deferreds согласно ид данные получаю. но и получаю пустые элементы массива. можно получить красивый массив вида [[name:lol, data: [[x1,y1]] ],[name:lol2, data[[x2,y2],[x3,y3]]]] ?

Comment: да можно, обновляю ответ

Comment: @des1roer, обновил ответ